# Animate and change color of icon on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation, android-xml

I have a layout like this for my icon:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/icon_layout"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_globe"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make it so that if the layout is clicked:

1. The image "pops" slightly (scales it from `24dp` to `32dp` and then back to `24dp`)
2. Change (fade in) the color of the icon to red as it's scaling

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to set the background of your LinearLayout to a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) that emits a "red" drawable in its pressed state. For the animation, you'll have to define an [animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) in XML, then run that animation with:

```
ImageView iconLayout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_layout);
Animation expandAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.icon_expand);
iconLayout.startAnimation(expandAnimation);
```

Comment: What would the animation file look like to do the "pop" that I need? Also, a StateListDrawable would change the color of the icon **immediately**, but is there a way to *fade in* the color to red?

Comment: For color fade you can use ObjectAnimator as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14282231/1076585). If you read the android annotation documentation, you should be able to construct your animation based on the examples they give.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
imageView.animate().scaleX(newScaleX).scaleY(newScaleY).alpha(1).setDuration(300).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for fade in out

```
private Animation animation;

animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
            animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in

            //Use this animation where ever you want to use
            icon.startAnimation(animation);
```